# vb6 print Crystal report without preview and click print button

Tags: printing, crystal-reports, vb6

I am using VB6 and Crystal Report 8.5 and I want to print my report directly with the default printer without preview and clicking the print button. I have this code and but when ever I try to print it shows me the preview and i have to click Print button for print process
Here is my code

```
With MAIN.CR
    .Reset: MAIN.InitCrys
    .ReportFileName = App.Path & "\Reports\rptCashInvoice.rpt"
    .Connect = "POS"

    strTitle = "Cash Invoice"

    strSelFormula = "{Cash_Sales.InvoiceNo} ='" & InvoiceNo & "'"

    .SelectionFormula = strSelFormula

            .WindowTitle = strTitle

            .ParameterFields(0) = "prmCompany;" & CurrBiz.BUSINESS_NAME & ";True"
            .ParameterFields(1) = "prmAddress;" & CurrBiz.BUSINESS_ADDRESS & ";True"
            .ParameterFields(2) = "prmContactInfo;" & CurrBiz.BUSINESS_CONTACT_INFO & ";True"

            .PrintReport
            .DiscardSavedData = True
End With
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like:

```
Dim crxApp As CRAXDRT.Application
Dim crxRpt As CRAXDRT.Report

Set crxApp = New CRAXDRT.Application
Set crxRpt = crxApp.OpenReport("C:\MyReport.rpt")

crxRpt.PrintOut False, NoCopies
```

If you need to print the report on other printer than default, try to use SelectPrinter.

[Look at this page](http://visualbasic.ittoolbox.com/groups/technical-functional/vb-crystalreports-l/printing-crystal-report-from-vb6-without-preview-1235368).